# Android: have 'up' button have same animation as back button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I've searched around and I can't seem to find an answer to this that works.

I'm using `<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".HomeScreen" />` to apply the parent screen.

I'm using the slide_in_left, slide_out_right etc xmls, and have got this in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

This works perfectly for everything except the up button in the action bar, which behaves as if I'm moving forward in the hierachy, not back (slides out to the left). Is there any way to change this?

Thanks!

Comment: any solution yet? Having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm still hoping someone has an answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find is by overriding the action called by the up button, making it operate as a back button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This code is in the child activity, the one with the up button.